# How to pass sensitive data to helm values file that is committed?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I am installing `kube-prometheus-stack` with Helm and I am adding some custome scraping configuration to Prometheus which requires authentication. I need to pass `basic_auth` with `username` and `password` in the `values.yaml` file.

The thing is that I need to commit the `values.yaml` file to a repo so I am wondering how can I have the username and password set on values file, maybe from a secret in Kubernetes or some other way?

```yaml
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
      - job_name: myjob
        scrape_interval: 20s
        metrics_path: /metrics
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - myservice.default.svc.cluster.local:80
        basic_auth:
          username: prometheus
          password: prom123456
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scrape config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) support specifying `password_file` parameter, so you can mount your own secret in volumes and volumemMounts:

Disclaimer, haven't tested it myself, not using a kube-prometheus-stack, but i guess something like this should work:

```yaml
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
      - job_name: myjob
        scrape_interval: 20s
        metrics_path: /metrics
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - myservice.default.svc.cluster.local:80
        basic_auth:
          password_file: /etc/scrape_passwordfile

    # Additional volumes on the output StatefulSet definition.
    volumes:
    - name: scrape_passwordfile
      secret:
        secretName: scrape_passwordfile
        optional: false

    # Additional VolumeMounts on the output StatefulSet definition.
    volumeMounts:
    - name: scrape_passwordfile
      mountPath: "/etc/scrape_passwordfile"
```

Another option is to ditch `additionalScrapeConfigs` and use `additionalScrapeConfigsSecret`to store whole config inside secret

```yaml
    ## If additional scrape configurations are already deployed in a single secret file you can use this section.
    ## Expected values are the secret name and key
    ## Cannot be used with additionalScrapeConfigs
    additionalScrapeConfigsSecret: {}
      # enabled: false
      # name:
      # key:
```

Comment: I've tested this locally and it works like a charm! Thank you!